# Meteor Tutorial Application: stuck after step 2

Tags: meteor

I'm a super noob trying to learn how to use Meteor, and am already stuck on the 2nd part of the Tutorial App.

My question is: Where can I find the imports directory? And, is there a search function/shortcut I can use to find directories in Sublime text?

Thanks for the help

---

Then we create some new files in the imports/ directory:

2.2  Add starter HTML code imports/ui/body.html »

---

Comment: Create the "imports" directory right in the root of your app, where the ".meteor" folder is.

Comment: you have to create the imports directory.   sublime will search files and folders automatically, it's not finding it because it doesn't exist yet